# How do I link my button to the selected state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

Now, I have sort of asked this question already, but this time it's a little different. Since my last question, I have received several answers and excellent advice, and I did some extensive research as well. I am using xcode, and coding for iOS 6.

My question specifically is how do I keep my button in a temporary "selected" state when pressed? Like I want it to stay pressed through the duration of the sound and then switch back to the default image.

My button is mostly linked up through interface builder, because it's easy and less code to write. I have the sound coded in my button's IBAction to play when pressed and I have the second image that it changes to when pressed, however the Image isn't set in my code it is set in Interface Builder.

I've seen several code that seems like it would work wonders if I knew how to correctly input it. Which leads me to a second part of my question.

Can someone help me set it up?

for example:

`[btnClear setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`

This seems like it would do the trick in my head. I just don't know which variable of mine to replace "btnClear" with and setBackgroundImage isn't showing up as a command.

On my other question I received and answer in the form of a comment that made the most sense but they didn't elaborate, it was:

"you can set image for Selected state of your button, and on touchUpInside set property selected = YES.

So I have the image I want in the selected state, and my button is linked for touchUpInside, but the only "property" or action it has is to play the sound, and because my button's images are set in Interface Builder I'm not really sure how I can set selected = YES without coding a new class which sets up the image.

Now if that's what I have to do, that's fine, but I need some guidance setting that up I am highly familiar with Objective-C it's just I'm new to these default classes in the iOS SDK I'm still getting a hold of things and having to refer to tutorials every now and again.

Here's a link to my other question if it helps:

[How do I make a button stay pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436866/how-do-i-make-a-button-stay-pressed/18437301?noredirect=1#18437301)

Again, I already have everything set up regarding the Image in Interface Builder, I'm just not sure how to fit the selected state option it into my already existing button action.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is a button property:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

(Or with a more descriptive name!)  Hook this up to your button in Interface Builder.  Then when you want to switch to the selected image (which you said is already in IB, right?), simply do this:

```
self.button.selected = YES;
```

And to turn back to the default image:

```
self.button.selected = NO;
```